# Apex test class code coverage issue

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Iam having trouble with a code coverage issue in one of my apex class code coverage please find the code below.

Apex class:

```
public class Executeapex {

public static void executethismethod(){
    
    DELETE [SELECT Id, CC_ContractType__c, CC_Entity__r.Name, CC_ProductBook__r.Name, createdDate FROM CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c];

List<AggregateResult> l_epv = [SELECT CC_ContractType__c, CC_Entity__c, CC_Entity__r.Name E, CC_ProductBook__c, CC_ProductBook__r.Name FROM CC_EntityPropertyValue__c WHERE CC_ProductBook__r.Name != null AND CC_ContractType__c != 'All' AND CC_ProductBook__r.CC_Parent__c = null GROUP BY CC_ContractType__c, CC_Entity__c, CC_Entity__r.Name, CC_ProductBook__c, CC_ProductBook__r.Name];
List<CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c> l_cepm = new List<CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c>();
for(AggregateResult epv : l_epv){
    CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c cepm = new CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c();
    cepm.CC_ContractType__c = String.valueOf(epv.get('CC_ContractType__c'));
    cepm.CC_Entity__c = String.valueOf(epv.get('CC_Entity__c'));
    cepm.CC_ProductBook__c = String.valueOf(epv.get('CC_ProductBook__c'));
    l_cepm.add(cepm);
}
insert l_cepm;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/Executeapex');
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    ApexPages.AddMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM,'Pricing Calculation successful!'));
    
}
```

}

Test class:

```
    @isTest
  public class Test_Executeapex {
    
  public static testmethod void  test_executethismethod(){
        CC_Entity__c e = new CC_Entity__c();
        e.Name = 'Test';
        e.CC_Country__c = 'FRANCE';
        e.CC_DefaultLanguage__c = 'English';
        insert e;  
        
        SG_ProductBook__c pb = new SG_ProductBook__c();
        pb.Name = 'Test Book';
        insert pb;  
        
        CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c epm = new CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c();
        epm.CC_ContractType__c = 'Routine Maintenance';
        epm.CC_Entity__c = e.Id;
        epm.CC_ProductBook__c = pb.Id;
        
      test.startTest();
       // Executeapex exeap = Executeapex(epm.Id);
        Executeapex.executethismethod();
        test.stopTest();
        //DELETE[SELECT Id, CC_ContractType__c, CC_Entity__r.Name, CC_ProductBook__r.Name, createdDate FROM CC_ContractEntityProductMatrix__c];
        
        
        
    }

}
```

I get a code coverage of 64 % only please find the image below.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: @rahulgawale here in my code i called the apex method but it did not cover which should have.

Comment: Its because you didn't insert the `CC_EntityPropertyValue__c ` records in your testmethod.

Comment: @rahulgawale thanks i missed that one thanks for this.

Comment: @rahulgawale it worked btw